# I want to generate JSON schema based on input JSON data programmatically using C#. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, json

Below is a sample JSON data. I would like to programmatically get it's JSON schema. The schema generation should happen dynamically, which means JSON data can keep changing in different requests

```
{
    "Users":[{
        "Individual": {
            "IndividualInfo": {
                "Title": "Mr",
                "Suffix": "",           
                "CountryOfBirth": "US",
                "CountryOfCitizenship": {
                    "Country": [
                        "US", "CA"
                    ]
                },
                "CountryOfResidence": "US",
                "USGreencard": "No",            
                "CountryOfMarriage": "US",
                "VIP": "Yes"
            },
            "IdentificationInfo": {
                "Identification": [{
                        "Country": "US",                    
                        "ValidToDate": "12/31/2037"
                    }, {
                        "Country": "CA",                    
                        "ValidToDate": "12/31/2019"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "EmploymentInfo": {
                "Employment": [{
                        "EmployerName": "EmpNameee",                    
                        "WorkspaceName": "SDAS"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Let us know how you go

Comment: You might just use the `dynamic` type.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: @Equalsk Could u please elaborate on the approach

Answer (score 0):

Could JSON.NET Schema would do the trick. This is what it suggest:

JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();

JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Users));

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the line generator.Generate(typeof(Users)) , you are hardcoding the type as 'Users' . As I told u that the input JSON is dynamic, so I can't specify type. It has to form dynamically

Comment: So parsing it first like JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(@"yourjsonhere") ty! will keep myself a mental note. Learning new things everyday. Cheers

Comment: Thank u. It is not working. Could you suggest any other approach.

Comment: I have not tried it myself but did you check NJsonSchema for .NET?

Comment: Yes, it's not giving the desired result